# Передача параметра php

Tags: php

Добрый день. Есть разметка

```
<div>
<h1>Статья 1</h1>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="sandId">Добавить статью</button>
</form>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Статья 2</h1>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="sandId">Добавить статью</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Все данные в разметку выводятся средствами php, вытягиваются из базы. У каждой статьи есть свой уникальный номер.
Нужно сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку sandId в файл- обработчик передавался id той записи,к которой прикреплена форма.
Пытался сделать так:

```
 <div>
    <h1>Статья 1</h1>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
    <button type="submit" name="sandId">Добавить статью</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h1>Статья 2</h1>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="1"/>
    <button type="submit" name="sandId">Добавить статью</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Но этот вариант мне не подходит, значения скрытых полей, а точнее id статей, берутся из базы, их не должен видеть пользователь. И иметь возможность изменять их прямо в браузере он тоже не должен.

Comment: Прошу прощение, если не очень понятно объяснил.

Comment: При реализации протоколов безопасности забудьте, что у вас есть страница. От пользователя может прийти **любой** HTTP запрос.

Comment: вы лучше бы начали с разделения логики и представления (пхп и разметки) в разных файлах, было бы куда проще

Comment: @vp_arth если можно, поподробнее. Мне просто нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку в блоке записи, которых(записей) может быть много. Отправлялся id этой записи, той в которой кнопка)

Comment: @teran хорошо, сейчас попробую отредактировать

Comment: Добавьте value прямо в кнопку(hidden тоже норм). Имеет ли возможность пользователь отредактировать это значение - не имеет значения) Он может отправить вам любые данные без браузера. Ваша задача, на сервере принять решение отдавать ли ему данные/выполнять ли действия по этому id.

Comment: @vp_arth, нужно это обкурить) хотел просто чтобы наверняка приходили более или менее надежные данные, но это же клиент...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать уравнение, которое бы при генерации страницы с формами вставляла в формы не настоящие данные идентификаторов записей из бд, а какие-то условные строки\цифры. Когда бы данные приходили от пользователя, то же уравнение высчитывало бы всё в обратном порядке. Важно добавить какую-то "соль", которая бы точно гарантировала, что расшифрованные данные относятся к какой-либо записи. Например, дату создания записи в БД. Но проще использовать [шифрование](https://habrahabr.ru/post/257439/). Или использовать логику хеширования паролей (проще всего).

Например, берём из базы идентификатор записи и дату-время создания этой записи (в качестве "соли"). Соединяем их вместе, приводим, например, к виду 174_2017-23-02_23-00 (лучше всего ИД записи писать не ожидаемо в начале, а где-нибудь в другом месте - между датой и временем. Пользователи ведь не знают, что и как вы тут крутите).

Дальше используем `password_hash()` ([документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php)). Получаем хэш вида `$2y$10$3KYZHiFhKHNB7.yJUGXJf.zR6Z8uc4.pdPsKbTTMDoApsp8CBY5qe`, который используем для вывода пользователю в скрытое поле.

При получении данных от пользователя сверяемся с тем, что получили, с тем, что должно быть. Например, с помощью `password_verify()` ([документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php))

Если пользователь захочет что-то подправить у себя на странице, то он не сможет узнать что это за данные и не удастся ему ничего сделать. Смысл, надеюсь, ясен.

Comment: По поводу хеширования - если на странице 30 таких кнопок - нужно будет посчитать 30 хешей, чтобы выяснить. Т.е. в любом случае - на сервере есть некий белый список, с чем сравнивать. Но если нет разницы, зачем платить больше? С шифрованием другая история, в принципе такой сценарий возможен. Но, все поля не зашифруешь - пользователю и поредактировать что-нибудь дать надо)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, буду копать в этом направлении. Я правильно понимаю, что если у меня в базе 30 таких записей, то мне нужно будет вытянуть их все, а потом перебирая и шифруя данные каждой из них сравнивать их при помощи password_verify()  с тем, что пришло от пользователя? Это не критично в плане эффективности? Чисто теоретически я думаю что таких записей и 30 скорее всего не наберется)

Comment: Хотя можно же попробовать добавить ещё одно поле с датой добавления  в таблицу БД, которое будет хэшировано. А передавать хэш даты добавления + хэш секретного слова, к примеру, конкатенируя эти хэши. Ну а после просто распарсить полученную строку. И искать напрямую в БД по полю.

Comment: Ну, примерно всё так, да. Пробуйте, экспериментируйте. Обычное хеширование - это относительно быстро. Суть уловили, а дальше - практика. Успехов.